# Which things can facebook access like contacts etc

Tags: privacy, facebook

I had two incidents .

1. I added `john` to my skype account and i exchaged few messages. Then i went home and was checking facebook . Then at right side i saw `Do you know  john` and it was his acoount
2. Then i had stored one person in mobile phone with name and phone and i never had any contact with him. But i still sometime see his name in do you know him . I have no mutual friends with as well.

Does it mean that facebook read my phone contacts and skype messages

Comment: Facebook is evil and you should've known that. Installing any of their software on your main phone/computer is suicide, just use the browser instead, which doesn't allow it to read any personal data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that, and a lot more if you use their mobile app. Also, they are not alone on harvesting everything; always read the app permissions list before installing an app, and consider whether you are willing to share your data with the app maker...

[image: FB app permissions on Android]